# How Do I Do This In JavaScript? Search Text On Page And If No Text Show Tick And If Text Show X

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage that has a lot of dynamic data showing usernames. This data isn't currently in a usable form but I want a simple way for our users to go onto a page which has a text box they can type in the username they want to use and it checks that page (JS + usernames on same page) and if no text showing then show a tick, they can use, and if username can be found then show an X.

Effectively:
1. User enters text in an edit box
2. Javascript searches page
3. JS shows image if true and image if false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in function for this task:

```
if (find('Thomas')) {
    // show image for found case
}
else {
    // Not found
}
```

Read mode about [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.find) method of window object.

Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VyFNt/

Comment: I like your answer dfsq. Though it does have one situation... Soon as you start typing it will show the X or Tick, but overall I am putting you as correct answer as yours was quicker to implement. Will need to test the other answer also, but you gave much more in various ways. Keep up the great work.

Answer (score 1):

use css for showing false image

```
<input type="text" id="check" />
```

now in JS

```
$('#check').keyup(function(){
 $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url: "serverpage_address.jsp",
                                cache: false,
                                async: true,
                                data: {'var_1' : val_1},
                                beforeSend:function(){useme();},
                                complete:function(){freeme();},
                        success:function(data){
                    //do your stuff here like iamge shown or anything
                                },
                                error:function(){/*notify about error*/}
                 });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. User enters text in edit box
2. Javascript function is called
3. Javascript function makes a RegEx search over the body of the page
4. If found add ok image, if not found nok image